# Multi-byte characters and C++ Streams

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, utf-8, filestream

I have code that finds some words in a `.txt` file (in the range of 9-25), and then finds those words in another `.txt` file, and saves them into a `.txt` file.

The problem is with multi-byte characters. The code works with symbols like `あきる` or `會`, but doesn't work with letters like `é`. In a `.txt` file, its just the letter `e`.

Also, I don't know if it helps, but when I try to print all the words into the console, it only prints words with English characters.

```cpp
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
void processFile(const fs::path filePath, const fs::path resultPath, const std::unordered_set<std::wstring>& dict) {
    std::wifstream fileIn(filePath, std::ios::binary);

    // Create a locale using UTF-8 encoding
    std::locale utf8_locale(fileIn.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);

    fileIn.imbue(utf8_locale);

    std::vector<int> indexes;
    std::wstring previousWord;
    bool twelveInRow = false;
    int counter = 0;

    std::vector<std::wstring> words;
    std::wstring word;
    wchar_t prev_ch = L' ';
    wchar_t ch;

    while (fileIn.get(ch)) {
        ch = towlower(ch);

        if (iswalpha(ch)) {
            word += ch;
        }
        else if (iswspace(ch) && !iswspace(prev_ch) && !word.empty()) {
            words.push_back(std::move(word));
            word.clear();
        }
        prev_ch = ch;
    }

    if (!word.empty()) {
        words.push_back(std::move(word));
    }

    fileIn.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
        std::wcout << words[i] << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
        const auto& word = words[i];
        if (dict.find(word) == dict.end()) {
            if (previousWord != L"astralcomplex65") {
                indexes.push_back(-1);
                previousWord = L"astralcomplex65";
            }
        }
        else {
            indexes.push_back(i);
            previousWord = word;
            counter++;
            if (counter >= 9 && counter <= 25) {
                twelveInRow = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (twelveInRow) {
        wchar_t prev_ch1 = L' ';
        wchar_t ch1;

        std::wifstream InFile(filePath, std::ios::binary);
        InFile.imbue(utf8_locale);
        //       std::filesystem::path filePath = std::filesystem::absolute(fileIn.getloc().name());
        std::wofstream file(resultPath / (randomName() + L"_Line_Matches" + L".txt"), std::ios::binary);
        // Set the locale for output using UTF-8 encoding
        file.imbue(utf8_locale);

        std::wstring content;
        content += filePath.wstring() + L'\n';
        for (auto i : indexes) {
            content += ((i == -1 ? L"" : words[i]) + L"\n");
        }
        content += L'\n';

        file << content;
        file.close();
        InFile.close();
    }
}

const std::unordered_set<std::wstring> loadDict(const fs::path path) {
    std::wifstream fileIn(path, std::ios::binary);

    // Create a locale using UTF-8 encoding
    std::locale utf8_locale(fileIn.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);

    fileIn.imbue(utf8_locale);

    std::unordered_set<std::wstring> words;
    std::wstring word;

    while (fileIn >> word) {
        words.insert(word);
    }

    fileIn.close();

    return words;
}
```

I tried to get the `é` letter by just copying the `.txt` file and creating another `.txt` file, and it works, so there is a problem with my massive indexes which have positions of characters that should be written in another `.txt` file.

Comment: é has more than one representations. Consider doing normalization first. https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Comment: @WeijunZhou i tested code without indexes massive which have positions of characters that should be written in file, and it works, so i guees i have a problem with getting position of 'é' type characters

Comment: Why are you reading the input file 1 `wchar_t` at a time? Some characters may require more than 1 `wchar_t`.  Since you are breaking up words only on whitespace, why not just use `operator>>`  instead and let it handle that for you? `while (fileIn >> word) { ... }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau It worked!!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one guy from comments gave an answer
basically i am putting characters in `std::vector<std::wstring> words;`
massive only one at a time, and somme characters may require more than 1 `wchar_T`, it's better to rewrite `while(fileIn.get(ch))` cycle to this

```
    while (fileIn >> word) {
        // Convert each character to lowercase
        std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), towlower);

        // Process the word
        if (iswalpha(word[0])) {
            words.push_back(std::move(word));
        }
        else if (!word.empty()) {
            // Handle the case where the word starts with a non-alphabetic character
            words.push_back(std::wstring(1, word[0]));
        }
    }
```